# Read multiple line from std::cin

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a unit test and I try to read some POST data from stdin, or cin. The data is like this:

```
callCount=1
page=/cs/admissions/admissions_tracker_result.jhtml?schoolId=436&classYear=2020
httpSessionId=xQIX_WS2vyua_JfEEKL0zAVRkxCLzMv-RM8ZJYuWfkaoA_IB6Ynn!788428762
scriptSessionId=5A7188C7ABF4B9F05D7CEB361E670361570
c0-scriptName=AdmissionScattergramService
c0-methodName=renderChart
c0-id=0
c0-e1=string:true
c0-e2=string:true
c0-e3=string:true
c0-e4=string:true
c0-e5=string:true
c0-e7=string:8
c0-e8=string:2
c0-e9=string:4
c0-e10=string:3
c0-e11=string:6
c0-e12=string:7
c0-e6=Array:[reference:c0-e7,reference:c0-e8,reference:c0-e9,reference:c0-e10,reference:c0-e11,reference:c0-e12]
c0-e13=string:true
c0-e14=string:true
c0-e15=string:true
c0-e16=string:true
c0-e17=string:true
c0-e18=string:true
c0-e19=string:true
c0-e20=string:true
c0-e22=string:1
c0-e23=string:2
c0-e24=string:3
c0-e25=string:4
c0-e26=string:0
c0-e21=Array:[reference:c0-e22,reference:c0-e23,reference:c0-e24,reference:c0-e25,reference:c0-e26]
c0-e27=string:true
c0-e28=string:true
c0-e30=string:AL
c0-e31=string:AK
c0-e32=string:AR
c0-e33=string:AS
c0-e34=string:AZ
c0-e35=string:CA
c0-e36=string:CO
c0-e37=string:CT
c0-e38=string:DC
c0-e39=string:DE
```

When I paste into the debugger, the program start runner automatically. I try to modify my code and use `std::getline(std::can, post)` instead of `std::cin>>post;` However, it didn't work.
Here is the code:

```
 std::string url;
  std::string post;
  printf("enter the url\n");
  std::cin>>url;
  printf("enter the post data\n");
  std::string line;

    while (true) {
      getline(std::cin, line);
      if (line.empty()) {
        break;
      }
    post += '\n' + line;
    }
```

It seems like `getline()` is non-blocking. And the variable `std::string post` is just leave empty.

Comment: You cannot do proper I/O if you don't check the return value of input operations.

Comment: I'm not familiar with I/O, std::string  and std::cin should be a safe option. I just try to get multiple line input from stdin, and I'd like to do it in a C++ way since it is safer. I try to take a look at the doc of get line, but I could not find anything. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getline` is in fact blocking. The issue you are facing is because of this line:

```
std::cin>>url;
```

It reads the `url` from a line, but **doesn't read the newline character**. When you then call `getline`, the stream is right in front of the newline character that was following the `url`, and you read it, getting an empty line. To address it, just call the `getline` once after reading the `url`, before entering your loop.

Comment: Seems like it still don't execute while (true) {
      getline(std::cin, line);
      if (line.empty()) {
        break;
      }
    post += '\n' + line;
    }

Comment: Are you sure you added an extra `getline` before the loop? You might have seen my answer with an incorrect advice before I edited it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will remember that. I never use getline before.